# stop function that passes parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently I am using this function to validate if the inputs within a form are complete, but the problem is that when using this function a parameter pass is performed.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    }else{
      funcion_upp_data();
      Breaker();
    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
   }, false);
  });
  }, false);
  })();
```

my url:

[image]

[image]

when I click, my url changes and it's done like this:

[image]

that you should modify in the function so that this change is not made in the url.

Comment: Adding an event listener inside another event listener is almost always a mistake.

Comment: When using the GET method all the names and values will sent to the same page, or file you've specified in the `action` attribute through the URL. This is the way your form communicates. You could either change the method to POST or use JavaScript to send the data from the form manually, without having side effects, like the URL that changes.

Comment: @Pointy Except if the outer one is `load` or `DOMContentLoaded`...

Comment: @FZs oh, yea, good point

Comment: in this case I use this function because it allows me to validate if there are empty inputs. what should I change in this function or what other function should I use so that the url is not changed